# Qt Brainstorming/optimizing for QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a design like that:[image]

Generally there will be 200-300 rows. I'm thinking of doing it using QTableWidget.

But I want it to load fast and be optimized. If I put QWidget in column with setCellWidget, I think it will slow down. How can I optimize better, what should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: There's not much point in optimising for such a small number of rows.

Comment: "I think it will slow down" - did you test it?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I currently have an application designed in Qt like https://i.imgur.com/YMYyiZJ.png. There are 150 rows. It takes 5-6 seconds to load. Of course, this time has an effect on the code I wrote. I am updating the table using setItem, setCellWidget. But the GUI becomes unresponsive before these updates are finished.

Comment: Use a separate worker thread to update the table without losing GUI responsiveness - see for example https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/

Comment: I am using Qt Signal with emit function. It shows the GUI while updating but not clickable until load all qtablewidget data. So I am looking better way to load fast and clickable while loading data. For example, Should I use QTableView instead of QTableWİdget? With custom item delegate?

Comment: @Dream59 using a delegate might be faster if the view doesn't normally show all items, as Qt is smart enough to paint only visible items. The fact that loading 150 rows takes 5-6 seconds makes me think that there might be some issues in those custom widgets (maybe they are too complex, or they are not well optimized for repetitive painting if you're using custom widgets). Note that allowing interaction while the table is being updated is not a very good idea: since the loading time is relatively small, you could just add a loading dialog.